# Photoshop CC: text stuck in all caps

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, typesetting

I am adding text to an image in Photoshop CC and all the time the text is in ALL CAPS. I can't find a way to get it to normal caps. What should I do? Here is what my screen looks like:

[image: Text stuck in ALL CAPS]

Answer (score 14):

1. Open your **Character Panel:**

[image]

2. Untick the **All Caps** setting in the **Character Panel:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You must have the `All Caps` checkbox ticked in the Character palette. Turn this off and you should be good.

[image: character palette]

Answer (score 0):

as other said you are in all caps.
first click on your textbox and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>